# simple odata4j - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, odata

I'm trying to connect to an OData service using odata4j.
ATM its just that bit of code:

```
public class Main extends AbstractExample{
    private static String service = "http://server/ApplicationData.svc";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ODataConsumer.Builder b = ODataConsumers.newBuilder(service);
        b.setClientBehaviors(new BasicAuthenticationBehavior("dev","dev"));
        ODataConsumer consumer = b.build();
    }
}
```

The application already exits with error on the first line in main:

```
ODataConsumer.Builder b = ODataConsumers.newBuilder(service);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.getConsumerClass(ODataConsumers.java:71)
at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.<init>(ODataConsumers.java:47)
at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers$Builder.<init>(ODataConsumers.java:37)
at org.odata4j.consumer.ODataConsumers.newBuilder(ODataConsumers.java:103)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 7 more
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:838]
```

I sadly have no idea what is possibly causing that. Hope someone can help out here!

Best regards
Simon

Answer (score 0):

after a half day of searching, 3 times checking and now posting the question I just recogniced that my build path wasn't set up correctly.
Its now working.
Reference

```
odata4j-0.7.0-clientbundle.jar
```

was missing.

Simon